# Fade from one stylesheet to the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I thought this might just be possible with jQuery or JavaScript - could someone tell me if it is possible to fade from one stylesheet's styles to another? If so, how would one do it?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [automatic jquery stylesheet switcher](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266275/automatic-jquery-stylesheet-switcher)

Comment: I can see why this got a downvote, but thinking about it, it's actually a pretty neat and flexible idea. Some synthesizers have the idea of scenes. A bunch of settings with numeric values, you can then transition at will between scenes at a user defined rate. The ability to transition numeric values between stylesheets would look amazing. It would have to be custom script though I think.

Comment: While you can swap style sheets, there's no concept of animating between the two. You'd have to set that up manually via JS.

Comment: Hot damn, I'm going to write a plugin to do this. I can picture it in my head. CSS3 has transitions, but I don't think it quite has the level of sophistication I'm imagining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best way I can think of:

```
$( body ).fadeOut( function() {
    // Switch the stylesheet
    // And then:
    $( this ).fadeIn();
} );
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use this as a permanent solution. But is there a way to fade directly between the two stylesheets?

Comment: Nope, nothing can calculate every single rule of all the stylesheets. If there were, it'd be too much computative to use.

Comment: I would have thought so. This code snippet is great as well. It will add a nice touch to my app.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
        var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
        $('body').hide().fadeIn(1000);  
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+rel+'" type="text/css" />');
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" rel="layout.css">Change to layout 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="layout2.css">Change to layout 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" rel="layout3.css">Change to layout 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery animate.
But you would have to specify all the rules in the animate command.