# Jquery CSS Fade to and fade back different css files

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, linux

I'm trying to find the best way to be able to call for a style sheet change for 5 seconds or a set ammount of time then go back to the default. But i would like it to fade to the style then fade out to default.

```
jQuery('head').append('<link id="skinstyle" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.'+s+'.css" type="text/css" />').fadeto(2000);
```

Thats how i'm trying to do it right now but its just changing no fade.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982006/fade-from-one-stylesheet-to-the-other

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1. You must set an opacity to the `.fadeTo()` function. Like `.fadeTo(miliseconds, opacity)`
2. `.fadeTo()` works just for visual elements, you can't `fade` a `<link>`, a `<script>` or a `<meta>`

Answer (score 0):

fadeTo() just changes element opacity, what I am assuming you are trying to do is substitute a different CSS rule for given CSS selectors (classes, etc.) and animate the change.  So if some class goes from having a height of 100px to 200px, you would animate the difference between the two.

Unfortunately you would need to rely on animate() to do something like this, and it does not work on a linked CSS element like that.  There is no functionality within jQuery itself that will do what you want.

I might however suggest an alternative.  If you use the proper extension provided by jQueryUI, you could utilize the switchClass() method to change the class of elements with properties animated.  Though for this case, you would need to actually change class names, not just override class properties with a new style sheet.